# Running Redis on Travis CI

Tags: express, redis, travis-ci

I just included a Redis Store in my Express application and got it to work.

I wanted to include this Redis Store in Travis CI for my code to keep working there. I read in the Travis Documentation that it is possible to start Redis, with the factory settings.

In my project, I don't use the factory settings, I wrote my own `redis.conf` file which specifies the port and the password.

So I added the following line to my `.travis.yml` file:

```
services:
  - redis-server --port 6380 --requirepass 'secret'
```

But this returns the following on Travis CI:

```
$ sudo service redis-server\ --port\ 6380\ --requirepass\ \'secret\' start
  redis-server --port 6380 --requirepass 'secret': unrecognized service
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to customize the option for Redis on Travis CI, I'd suggest not using the services section, but rather do this:

`before_script: sudo redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf --port 6380 --requirepass 'secret'`

The services section runs services using their init/upstart scripts, which may not support the options you've added in there. The command is also escaped for security reasons, hence the documentation only hinting that you can list normal service names in that section.

Comment: Is there any way of doing the same thing on the new container-based infrastructure?

Comment: Do I need to background this process on my own? It kinda looks like my travis test is hanging with `Ready to accept connections`? Not really sure what's going on...

Comment: (too late to edit comment) - backgrounding it did the trick. aka `sudo redis-server [...] &`

Comment: this command can only execute on Linux, what about OSX and Windows?