# How do I run redis on Travis CI?

Tags: django, unit-testing, redis, celery

I am practicing unit testing using django

**In items/tests.py**

```
class NewBookSaleTest(SetUpLogInMixin):

def test_client_post_books(self):

    send_post_data_post = self.client.post(
            '/booksale/',
            data = {
                'title':'Book_A',
                }
            )

    new_post = ItemPost.objects.first()
    self.assertEqual(new_post.title, 'Book_A')
```

**In views/booksale.py**

```
class BookSale(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

login_url = '/login/'

def get(self, request):
    [...]

def post(self, request):

    title = request.POST.get('title')

    saler = request.user

    created_bookpost = ItemPost.objects.create(
                user=saler,
                title=title,
                )

    # redis + celery task queue
    auto_indexing = UpdateIndexTask()
    auto_indexing.delay()

        return redirect(
               [...]
                )
```

when I run unit test, raise redis connection error

```
 redis.exceptions.ConnectionError
```

I know when I running redis-server and celery is error will solve

but when I run unit test in `Travis CI` I can't run redis-server and celery in Travis CI

So, I found this [link](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#Redis)

I try insert this code in .travis.yml

```
language:
    python
python:
    - 3.5.1
addons:
    postgresql:"9.5.1"
install:
    - pip install -r requirement/development.txt

service:
    - redis-server

# # command to run tests
script:
    - pep8
    - python wef/manage.py makemigrations users items
    - python wef/manage.py migrate
    - python wef/manage.py collectstatic --settings=wef.settings.development --noinput
    - python wef/manage.py test users items --settings=wef.settings.development
```

but it shows same error

so I found next [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297703/running-redis-on-travis-ci)

```
before_script:
    - sudo redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf --port 6379 --requirepass 'secret'
```

but... it show same error...

how can I running redis-server in travis ci?

Answer (score 2):

If you have not solve the problem now, here is a solution.

Remove the service line.

Redis is provided by the test environment as a default component, so

```
service:
    - redis-server
```

will be translated as:

```
service redis start
```

In this problem, we want to customize redis to add password auth. So we doesn't need travis ci to start redis service. Just use the `before_script`.

And after all, your .travis.yml should be this:

```
language:
    python
python:
    - 3.5.1
addons:
    postgresql:"9.5.1"
install:
    - pip install -r requirement/development.txt
before_script:
    - sudo redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf --port 6379 --requirepass 'secret'
# # command to run tests
script:
    - pep8
    - python wef/manage.py makemigrations users items
    - python wef/manage.py migrate
    - python wef/manage.py collectstatic --settings=wef.settings.development --noinput
    - python wef/manage.py test users items --settings=wef.settings.development
```